# Perl: How to substitute the content after pattern CLOSED

Tags: regex, perl

So I cant use $' variable

But i need to find the pattern that in a file that starts with the string “by: ” followed by any characters , then replace whatever characters comes after “by: ” with an existing string $foo

im using $^I and a while loop since i need to update multiple fields in a file.

I was thinking something along the lines of [s///]

```
s/(by\:[a-z]+)/$foo/i
```

I need help. Yes this is an assignment question but im 5 hours and ive lost many brain cells in the process

Comment: `s/by: \K[a-z]+/$foo/i`

Comment: a-z is not "whatever characters".  which did you actually want?

Comment: @ikegami, wow, I've been using Perl for 20 years and I've never learned `\K`. That's awesome.

Comment: @showaltb, It was introduced in 5.10, IIRC. `s/by: \K[a-z]+/$foo/i` is more efficient than `s/(by: )[a-z]+/$1$foo/i`. Note that `s/by: [a-z]+/by: $foo/i` isn't equivalent to them because of `/i`.

Comment: `s/by:\K.*([a-z])*/\u\L$1 \E\u$foo/ig;`  was my solution which accomplished the warranted substitution

Comment: @Boschko, That doesn't do what the question asks at all.

Comment: @ikegami `s/by:\K.*([a-z])*/$foo/ig;` does

Comment: That's a pretty awful version of what I previously posted. `(...)*` makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami if it works it works, youve been a huge help thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your substitution:

1. You say you want to match `by:` (space after colon), but your regex will never match the space.
2. The pattern `[a-z]+` means to match one or more occurrences of letters `a` to `z`. But you said you want to match "any characters". That might be zero characters, and it might contain non-letters.
3. You've replaced the match with `$foo`, but have lost `by:`. The entire matched string is replaced with the replacement.
4. No need to escape `:` in your pattern.
5. You're capturing the entire match in parentheses, but not using that anywhere.

I'm assuming you're processing the file line-by line. You want "starts with the string `by:` followed by any characters". This is the regex:

```
/^by: .*/
```

`^` matches beginning of line. Then `by:` matches exactly those characters. `.` matches any character except for a newline, and `*` means zero-or more of the preceding item. So `.*` matches all the rest of the characters on the line.

"replace whatever characters that come after `by:` with an existing string `$foo`. I assume you mean the contents of the variable `$foo` and not the literal characters `$foo`. This is:

```
s/^by: .*/by: $foo/;
```

Since we matched `by:`, I repeated it in the replacement string because you want to preserve it. `$foo` will be interpolated in the replacement string.

Another way to write this would be:

```
s/^(by: ).*/$1$foo/
```

Here we've captured the text `by:` in the first set of parentheses. That text will be available in the `$1` variable, so we can interpolate that into the replacement string.

Comment: how would i make it so i doesn't carry the content over from line underneath?

Comment: @Boschko what do you mean?  show your complete perl command in your question

Comment: @ysth right now the only command that works is `s/by: *\K[a-z].*/$nameLowercase/ig;` but i also need to  only make the first letter of the user’s name upper case.                    your command would somehow append the following line of the document which Im reading from to the end of my string its a mess man, im a mess

Comment: @ysth this is my exact question  If you find the pattern, starts with the string “by: ” followed by any characters , then replace whatever characters comes after  “by: ” with the user name that was provided from user input($foo).  Make only the first letter of the user’s name upper case.

Comment: @Boschko if it is appending the next line you are doing something strange.  you *must* show your entire perl command if you want help with that